# Rename Xcode Project with WatchKit Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have an app with a WatchKit extension that I'm wanting to rename. I thought I could just rename the project from Xcode but when I do that it crashes. I'm using Xcode 6.3.1.

Comment: instead of renaming project name just update BundleDisplayName key in info.plist

Comment: Yep i tried doing this - easiest way is to change the display name in both the main app and the watch app extension

Comment: The crash when renaming a project or a target is a known issue that will be corrected in future version of Xcode. You can try to install the GM of Xcode 6.3.2 from here : https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Comment: I have this problem and app name is changed successfully but on iPhone inside the Watch app there's still old name. I tried everything.

Comment: would really like to know how it's possible to rename a project WITH a watch app